# Insert a doc file into a column in SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to save a doc file in a field in SQL Server. That doc file can be contains text, charts, tables and pictures.

I want to save this file in a field and whenever I want, I  able to search in these doc files and find my search title.

how can i do this ?

Comment: Have you looked at the `filestream` feature? I think this approach makes sense when trying to store doc's in mssql. Benefits of file storage with the management features of sql. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993.aspx

Comment: Also a C# howto http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/128657/How-Do-I-Use-SQL-File-Stream

Comment: do you mean that you want to search the content of doc file saved as byte array in your databae?

Answer (score 3):

make a column of datatype `varbinary(max)` in your table and then try-

```
string filePath = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;  
string filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
string ext = Path.GetExtension(filename);
string contenttype = String.Empty;
 switch(ext)
{
    case ".doc":
        contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-word";
        break;
    case ".docx":
        contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-word";
        break;
}
 if (contenttype != String.Empty)
{

    Stream fs = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;
    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
    Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);

    //insert the file into database
    string strQuery = "insert into tblFiles(Name, ContentType, Data)" +
       " values (@Name, @ContentType, @Data)";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = filename;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContentType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value
      = contenttype;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Data", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = bytes;
    InsertUpdateData(cmd);
    lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;  
    lblMessage.Text = "File Uploaded Successfully";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can Create a new db field as type `VARBINARY(MAX)` in SQL which can hold any data. And to save Doc files to it,i will help you with an example.

```
        // Read the file and convert it to Byte Array

        string filePath = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;  
        string filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath);

        Stream fs = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;

        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);

        Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);



        //insert the file into database

        string strQuery = "insert into tblFiles(Name, Data)" +

           " values (@Name, @Data)";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = filename;



        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Data", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = bytes;

        InsertUpdateData(cmd);

        lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;  

        lblMessage.Text = "File Uploaded Successfully";
```

here the Field `DATA` is defined as `VarBinary(max)` in SQL.

For you second requirement,TO search a text inside the DOC, Please Refer [Configure and Manage Filters for Search](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4b7884ac-b0b0-4a3a-ac44-b2ab1e4aa6d0/search-a-word-or-sentence-inside-files-saved-in-sql-server?forum=sqlsearch)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks my friends
but i want to able to search in my doc files. 
doc files can contains tables and tables can contains any type of data such as text,numbers and ....
also charts and pictures can be like as tables.
and i don't want to save the path of my docs in a field and any time i need to search first i open the file and then search.
i want to save that doc file into a field and search on the field